# fix a banner on top of my Tumblr

Tags: tumblr, banner

I don't know much about HTML and having a basic idea like changing colors, place an element in the left or right place etc. Someone on the internet made a custom tumblr code for me, but at the time i didn't ask for the header/banner thing to stay fixed at the top so the images could scroll but actually it is not scrolling. Here is the code, which I already tried changing it to achieve the desired functionality but no luck. Hope someone can help me. Thank you. !!

```
#container {

    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 741px; }

    small {
    font-size: 12px; }

    blockquote {
    border-left: 3px solid #EEEEEE;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
    padding-left: 10px; }

 #header {

    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 741px; }

.banner {

    background-color: {color:Banner background};
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    max-width: 741px; }

.banner img {

    max-width: 741px;
    height: auto; }
```

and the page is this one: [www.elebenty.tumblr.com](http://www.elebenty.tumblr.com)

Comment: Just to clarify, the only 'fixed' element on the page is `#sidebar` (contains your avatar and links). You want this to scroll with the rest of the page?

Comment: Don't use the "fix" tag unless you're talking about FIX protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the header to stay in the same spot (so you can still see it when you scroll down the page), changed its position to fixed. So your #header css would become:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 741px; }
```

I'm not a hundred percent sure what you're asking, but I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, i dont know how to describe myself hehe, but whenever i do that my "ask/profile" section in the left moves and fuses with the banner, and it looks overlapped. :(